# How to choose a modem/router/WAP based on it's various features?

Tags: router, modem, wireless-access-point

In the last 4 years, I've gone through 5 modem routers, from the cheap boxes the ISP provides to slightly more expensive ones. Currently I have a WAP connected to a switch which is connected to a modem router. (the WAP and switch are in a seperate room to the router because of insulation in the walls which is shiny, and the wall is an external wall).

I'mw quite sick of buying a new router every 8 months, so I would like to know exactly what seperates the cheap routers and WAPs from the expensive ones? Is there a guide somewhere that goes through what different features are?

Comment: What's happening every 8 months that prompts you to buy a new one?  Is it frustration, failure, or something else?

Comment: It's not exactly 8 months, but roughly after 8-10 months the connection slows down (not just the internet speed, but like file transfers between local computers) and then it will just stop working  every hour or so, and require it to be restarted. (it's been 2 speedtouchs, 2 Belkin N1 Visions, and a Belkin G+ MIMO)

Comment: While I can't answer your questions I do propose that you begin by reading reviews of your service provider(s). Other customers may be having similar experiences to you. You may find that the provider is part or all of the problem. [dslreports.com](http://dslreports.com) may be a good starting point. Good luck!